# Inconsistent results reading Excel cells containing formula using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a situation where data is provided to my team in the form of an Excel spreadsheet. We want to automate importing data from that spreadsheet.  Trying to use C# and OpenXML, I'm seeing inconsistent behavior.

Cell D4 contains the formula "=HYPERLINK(AO4,AH4)", D5 contains the formula "=HYPERLINK(AO4,AH4)", and cell D6 contains the formula "=HYPERLINK(AO6,AH6)".

However, while OpenXML correctly reads the contents of D4 and D5, the Cell for D6 doesn't contain what I'd expect.

Inspecting each Cell in the debugger, I see something odd:

For D4, I see (and D5 is consistent):

```
CellFormula  "HYPERLINK(AO4,AH4)"
CellMetaIndex null
CellReference "D4"
CellValue     "-"
DataType      "str"
```

For D6, however:

```
CellFormula  ""
CellMetaIndex null
CellReference "D6"
CellValue     "-"
DataType      "str"
```

I'm a bit of a loss.  Why would CellFormula for two cells that *look* virtually identical return the formula in one case, and nothing in the other? (Both cells are of number format General).

The ClosedXML API lacks support for a couple of functions that we use (and we'd need to merge multiple workbooks, because it doesn't support references to external workbooks).  The Excel interop APIs can read the cells without issue, but that would require installing Excel on the server, fussing with permissions to get Excel interop to run correctly when launched from Task Scheduler, etc.

OpenXML seemed the cleanest solution, but I'm stumped why the API is behaving in a manner that seems inconsistent.  I don't see any differences between D4/D5 and D6 (and the issue recurs in other cells). I'm hoping there's something simple that I'm missing that someone here has encountered previous.

thanks,
-Steven

Comment: In order to help you, we would need to see your code and your file.  Write a small class that opens your file and loops through these cells so we can see what you are seeing in our debugger.  Then reduce the excel file down to just the parts that are important (and obfuscate the data if necessary).  Sometimes this excercise will reveal to you the solution.